# Region of Interest using OpenCV

Tags: .net, image, opencv, image-processing, face-recognition

With reference to the following Image can someone guide me how to go for extracting all the bulbs (b1, b2, b3, b4, b5) and putting them in separate image  (b1.jpg, b2.jpg, b3.jpg, b4.jpg, b5.jpg).

[image]

I can use a template, but the issue is  the size and shape of the bulbs are varying as you can see varying. (But the over all look of the bulb is still the same).

Any advice how to go for this using openCV?

Thanks and regards,

Heshsham

Comment: The title is a bit misleading.

Comment: Can you please tell me what according to you should be the title, so that next time I will keep this in mind before posting my questions ?

Comment: Object extraction, Template Matching, Image segmentation, any of these are more appropriate than your current title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Well if you are using templates, why not different templates? Keep a bunch of templates, match them against the image. Whichever gives you the best match is your candidate.
- Second way of doing this, if I understood the problem correctly, is to use SURF features. SURF is robust pretty much to skew, perspective, rotational changes, so it will surely help you in figuring out the bulbs.
- [Here](http://achuwilson.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/object-detection-using-surf-in-opencv-part-1/) is a link to showing off using SURF. Simple and elegant.

Comment: If I use templates do I need to match with 5 templates, for each bulb..? actually in real case i will be having about 100 bulbs, so dont you think template matching will be very slow? DO you think SURF will be a much better solution?

Comment: Yes, template matching will definitely be slow. While SURF would be rather much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If the background is always plain white as in your example you might do a simple treshold based segmentation and filter the resulting regions by size to get rid of the black artifacts.

Comment: Yes fortunately background is mostly noise free. But if I do thresholding, the bottom part of bulb also in black color will be lost along with noise.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Georg, very simple filter should be enough for you in this case.

To get more accuracy if your data are more complex than what you show, you might think about the information you are sure to get for each bulb.

I would say a contour, and a yellow bottom part.

Using those two information, I would think about discrimining all chrome elements, and start searching for a bulb above it.
Region growing might a correct solution, but long.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the noise, the image background is mostly white. But if I use a filter it will delete the black portion of the bulb. So my new images which i want to store in different image files will be less accurate. Also  in real case I will be having about 100 bulbs. Fortunately all the bulbs will be vertical or with an angle of +-10 degree. So your idea of searching those yellow portion seems good.

Comment: That is definitely what I woiuld be going to. When working on computer vision, you should always focus on what you are sure to find. In your case it is the chrome part